# How to write multiple lines in a file using multiline string? I really want to optimize the below code

Tags: python, python-3.x, filewriter, multilinestring

I am using `file_name.write` to write multiple line  considering spaces to write a file.

**Code:**

```
    file_handle.write('$TTL 1h\n')
    file_handle.write('@\tIN\tSOA\tns1.test.nimblestorage.com.\tis-ops.hpe.com. (\n'
                      )
    file_handle.write('\t\t\t%s\t; serial\n' % serial_number)
    file_handle.write('\t\t\t3h\t; refresh\n')
    file_handle.write('\t\t\t30m\t; retry\n')
    file_handle.write('\t\t\t30d\t; expire\n')
    file_handle.write('\t\t\t5m )\t; minimum\n')
    file_handle.write('\t\tNS\tns1.test.nimblestorage.com.\n')
    file_handle.write('\t\tNS\tns2.test.nimblestorage.com.\n')
    file_handle.write('\n')
```

But I need some multiline string code with all lines in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple quotes:

```
file_handle.write('''$TTL 1h
@\tIN\tSOA\tns1.test.nimblestorage.com.\tis-ops.hpe.com. (
\t\t\t{serial}\t; serial
...
'''.format(serial=serial_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons to want multi-line strings, in which case the answer by John Zwinck is the good one. However, if you want them for file I/O optimization:

**Don't bother**

Python already does the optimization for you: see the buffering option in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open